# Resultant group given some generators, modulo some relations between the generators.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I recently was trying to calculate some homology groups and reached the following situation:
the free abelian group generated by $\{a, b, c\}$ modulo the relations $\{a+c, -b-c, a+b\}$.

By using the Smith Normal Form, I got the quotient group is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Is there maybe an "easier" way of finding the quotient group?

Any help/reference is truly appreciated.

Comment: Do you think you could explain how to use Smith Normal Form to get this result? I've never seen an argument like that

Comment: Yeah. I actually have heard about the SNF, but only until last week I started reading about it. I followed this https://www.matem.unam.mx/~omar/mathX27/smith-form.html. 
The initial matrix is the 3x3 matrix obtained from the relations. The SNF I got is the diagonal matrix with diagional entries 1, 1, 2, where the only nontrivial elementary divisor is 2. I'm still trying to better understand the SNF as it seems to be a very convenient tool.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $R$ the subgroup generated by $\{a+b, -b-c, a+c\}$ and let $Q = \mathbb{Z} \langle a, b, c\rangle$/R. Then $Q$ is still generated by the cosets $[a], [b]$ and $[c]$, but immediately from the first and last relations we deduce that $[b]=-[a] = [c]$ and the remaining relation then says that $2[a] = 0$. It follows that $Q$ is either $\mathbb{Z}/2$ or $0$.

But if $Q$ is $0$ that means $a$ can be written as a linear combination of the generators of $R$ with integer coefficients:

$$a = x_1(a + b) + x_2(-b -c) + x_3(a+c) = (x_1 + x_3)a + (x_1 - x_2)b + (x_3 - x_2)c $$

i.e. there must be three integers $x_1, x_2, x_3$ such that $x_1 + x_3 = 1$, $x_1 - x_2 = 0$, and $x_3 - x_2 = 0$ (remember that we started with the *free* abelian group on these generators). But this is impossible since it implies $x_1 = x_2 = x_3$ and so $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, which is not an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And yes, I should have been more precise when I described the question. I did mean the free abelian group on those generators. This is a very nice answer, thanks for the help!